# Remove page numbers, but not headers

Tags: page-numbering

In my `\documentclass{article}`, I would like the last few pages (in essence appendix) to be without numbers, but retain the header (`\thispagestyle{empty}`) is so out of the question). Is there a way to turn off only page numbering? I use `fancyhdr` to construct my headers.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

How stupid of me. After I submitted my question, my search led me to [this page](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopageno) that solves the problem by using `\pagenumbering{gobble}`.

Comment: A couple of years too late to say this perhaps but "not stupid at all, sir!". You pretty much just saved my (academic) life!

Comment: @Roman: It's a good idea to mark your own answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

With the `fancyhdr` package, you can avoid page numbers simply by doing:

```
\fancyfoot{}
```

And you can still use `\pagestyle{fancy}` or anything else than `\pagestyle{empty}`.

Comment: Not sure why but this didn’t work for me.