# Remove page numbers in a »titlepage« environment

Tags: header-footer, page-breaking, page-numbering, titles

I use the titlepage enviroment in my thesis and want to remove the page numbers on my title pages (where I've got 2) pages. The titlepage enviroment does that for the first site automatically but not for the following pages so that there are page numbers with page 2 etc.

```
\begin{titlepage}
  % no page numbers at page 1
  \newpage
  % page numbers show up one page 2 and following pages
\end{titlepage}
```

I've already tried to get rid of the page numbers by trying the advices from »[removing page numbers, but not headers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/removing-page-numbers-but-not-headers)« and »[How to get rid of page numbers](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-nopageno)« but without any success.

**Edit #1**

Elmar was right, `\pagestyle{empty}` works when you place it in front of the enviroment like so:

```
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{titlepage}
  % no page numbers at page 1
  \newpage
  % now even the following pages omit the page numbering
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: I believe the `titlepage` is meant to be a single page. You can still enjoy `\pagestyle{empty}` the pages following the title page. There is a tradition to use roman page numbers for pages following the title page, including table of contents and other front matter, and to start the first chapter or section on page one (using arabic numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\pagestyle{empty}` doesnt work?

Comment: In fact it does. It turns out that I placed it wrong. It doesn't belong inside the titlepage enviroment as my linked articles said but just before that. So it works now, thanks for the support.

Comment: Yo gave good advice! Generally it would be great if you post a real answer instead of a question. Questions regarding the original question could be posted as comments.