# How to insert a header in the IEEE Conference template?

Tags: formatting, header-footer, titles, ieeetran

I have to include a header over my title like: 2016 IEEE 24th International Requirements Engineering Conference

I have got the IEEEtran V1.8 but can't figure out which usepackages I have to install for this header. Here is an example: [image: first_header]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%################DOCUMENT STARTS HERE######################
\begin{document}
%\fancyhdr[C]{2016 IEEE 24th International Requirements Engineering Conference} %zentrierte Kopfzeile
\title{My Paper Title}


% author names and affiliations
% use a multiple column layout for up to three different
% affiliations
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{M.Sc. John Dow}
\IEEEauthorblockA{Department of Economic Computer Science\\Economic Computer Science\\
University of California\\
xxx\\
Email: xxxyyy@university.com}}


% use for special paper notices
%\IEEEspecialpapernotice{(Invited Paper)}




% make the title area
\maketitle %RE 2016, Lisbon, Portugal \\ Research Paper

\begin{abstract}
Authoritatively matrix fully tested channels with market-driven portals. Energistically synthesize leading-edge data whereas distributed sources. Efficiently incentivize accurate resources and customized ROI. 

Continually procrastinate pandemic total linkage before bricks-and-clicks e-markets. Distinctively deploy cross-platform solutions for market-driven innovation. Appropriately iterate prospective solutions via competitive data. Text \cite{rupp2014}
\end{abstract}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}
% no \IEEEPARstart
This demo file is intended to serve as a ``starter file''
for IEEE conference papers produced under \LaTeX\ using
IEEEtran.cls version 1.8 and later.
% You must have at least 2 lines in the paragraph with the drop letter
% (should never be an issue)
I wish you the best of success.

\hfill mds
 
\hfill December 27, 2012

\subsection{Subsection Heading Here}
Subsection text here.


\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.


\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{Dissertation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you add a MWE and more specific requirements you are most likely to get appropriate help. For instance to me it's unclear if the caption got to be only over the title of the paper or if it should be on every page?

Comment: The term `header` is not clear here! Running page headers? Or just a line above the title of the paper?

Comment: Just a line above the title of the first page

Comment: @Ruben: This is not working: \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhdr[C]{2016 IEEE 24th International Requirements Engineering Conference} \title{My Paper}

Comment: @maxmin: That's possible due to `\pagestyle{empty}` of `titlepage`

Comment: Does anyone know about the IEEEtran V1.8? It includes about 500 code lines and I can't figure out the usepackage I need for the first header line ... should I post the complete code here? Could that help?

Comment: Just add a minimal example of your `.tex` manuscript, not the whole class. Without knowing what you actually do in terms of (La)TeX code it's impossible to help you. Btw: If you need to add only one line above your titel you don't need `fancyhdr` -- which helps you to actual headers.

Comment: @maxmin: The `IEEETran` class always using `twocolumn` mode. I don't know whether such a line above the actual title is useful at all. It might be rejected anyway

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: There is no such line in the code

Comment: @maxmin: Which line?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I have read the last year published papers from this conference (Beijing, China) and they all have this first header. Do you have experience with conference papers?

Comment: @maxmin: My last conference stuff is long ago. Please add your document here, such that users can help you. 'Does not work' is not useful

Answer (score 3):

This solution defines a custom meta-data command `\titleheader` that collects the information you want to put above the title in the canonical way, i.e.

```
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
```

Then next 6 lines of code take care of inserting this information at the right spot.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\st@red@title\@title
  \def\@title{%
    \bgroup\normalfont\large\centering\@titleheader\par\egroup
    \vskip1.5em\st@red@title}
}
\makeatother

\title{A Serious Game for Eliciting Social Engineering Security Requirements}
\titleheader{2016 IEEE 24th International Requirements Engineering Conference}
\author{maxmin}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Excellent, thank you :-) but how can I remove the page number 1 from the header. The IEEE doesn't want side numbers.

Comment: @christianhupfer: Tks for the tidy up :-)

Comment: @maxmin -- you're welcome! Regarding your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6639/removing-page-numbers-but-not-headers

Comment: Thank you for the link. I might can say one of my 10 problems is solved. You made my day. See you soon definitely

Comment: How do I put a header like this on every page?

Comment: @BlkPengu - https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr