# Adding conference header to ieeetran[conference]

Tags: titles, ieeetran

I'm just gonna add a header to my `ieeetran` document based on [Ruben's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346965/how-to-insert-a-header-in-the-ieee-conference-template).

But no header is added after compilation.

Here is the `MWE`:

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4b
%% 2015/08/26
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%for copyright notice
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\footnotesize  978-1-4799-6773-5/14/\$31.00 \textcopyright2017 Crown\hfill}
    \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\st@red@title\@title
    \def\@title{%
        \bgroup\normalfont\large\centering\@titleheader\par\egroup
        \vskip1.5em\st@red@title}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{X}
\titleheader{2017 IEEE 999999th International Something Conference}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{X}
\IEEEauthorblockA{H}\\
J\\
I\\
Email: a@b.c}
}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual definition of `\title` is to define `\@title`, so even if there is the `\AtBeginDocument{...}` hook with the Ruben's nice idea, it will fail, if `\title` is used **after** `\begin{document}`, since `\title`  overrules `\@title` again.

Solution: Use `\title` and `\titleheader` **before** `\begin{document}`.

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4b
%% 2015/08/26
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%for copyright notice
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\footnotesize  978-1-4799-6773-5/14/\$31.00 \textcopyright2017 Crown\hfill}
    \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\st@red@title\@title%
  \def\@title{%
    \bgroup\normalfont\large\centering\@titleheader\par\egroup
    \vskip1.5em\st@red@title}
}
\makeatother

\title{X}

\titleheader{2017 IEEE 999999th International Something Conference}

\begin{document}


%\makeatletter
%\meaning\@title
%\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{X}
\IEEEauthorblockA{H}\\
J\\
I\\
Email: a@b.c}}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is a `\centering` in the `titleheader` command. I'd just removed it to get rid of centered title (i.e., align the header from left-hand side), but nothing is changed. How can I do that?

Comment: @Roboticist: The `\centering` issue has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: You mean I should open a new thread for the left-alignment of the header?

Comment: @Roboticist: Yes. Usually, the title page is set in a `\begin{center}...\end{center}` environment. I did not check whether this is true for `IEEEtran.cls` as well