# Left alignment of a conference header in ieeetran

Tags: ieeetran

This question is a continuation of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375489/adding-conference-header-to-ieeetranconference/375492#375489).

How can I align the header from left, like the figure below? (Removing `\centering` did not work).[image]

Thanks to @Christian Hupfer, here is my `MWE`:

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4b
%% 2015/08/26
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%for copyright notice
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\footnotesize  978-1-4799-6773-5/14/\$31.00 \textcopyright2017 Crown\hfill}
    \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\st@red@title\@title%
  \def\@title{%
    \bgroup\normalfont\large\centering\@titleheader\par\egroup
    \vskip1.5em\st@red@title}
}
\makeatother

\title{X}

\titleheader{2017 IEEE 999999th International Something Conference}

\begin{document}


%\makeatletter
%\meaning\@title
%\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{X}
\IEEEauthorblockA{H}\\
J\\
I\\
Email: a@b.c}}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply substitute `\centering` with `\raggedright` in the `\titleheader` definition (BTW, `\centering` was redundant).

MWE:

```
%% bare_conf.tex
%% V1.4b
%% 2015/08/26
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%for copyright notice
\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
    \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
    \def\@evenfoot{}%
}
\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
    {\footnotesize  978-1-4799-6773-5/14/\$31.00 \textcopyright2017 Crown\hfill}
    \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\algrule}[1][.2pt]{\par\vskip.5\baselineskip\hrule height #1\par\vskip.5\baselineskip}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\titleheader[1]{\gdef\@titleheader{#1}}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\st@red@title\@title%
  \def\@title{%
    \bgroup\normalfont\large\raggedright\@titleheader\par\egroup
    \vskip1.5em\st@red@title}
}
\makeatother

\title{X}

\titleheader{2017 IEEE 999999th International Something Conference}

\begin{document}


%\makeatletter
%\meaning\@title
%\makeatother

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{X}
\IEEEauthorblockA{H}\\
J\\
I\\
Email: a@b.c}}


\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There's a spurious space after `\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{{X}`. Put a comment at the end of that line.